# jQuery draggable - change the listener

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-droppable

I'm having a problem with the draggable/droppable objects. I have the draggable object set to be about 400px wide and 50px tall. The droppable is the same height, but the width is only about 80px.

My problem comes in when you try to drop the object onto the droppable. In order for the draggable to actually fire the drop listener the draggable has to almost be perfectly centered over the droppable in order for it to actually work and to fire the drop event listener.

Is there a way to modify the code so that it will use the corners to test the drop? It would appear that it tests the draggable objects placement based on its width over the droppable to detect if it's being dropped. I need to modify this so that it listens to the outer edges of the draggable object instead.

For instance if the object being dragged in the image below were to be dropped it would snap to the object titled "Step 1". Right now, that draggable would have to be half way over in order to actually snap to the droppable object.

[image]

Comment: It's incredibly difficult to advise without seeing code.

Comment: Why would seeing my code change anything?

Comment: Because we don't know what you've tried. What libraries are you using? What events are you detecting? Are you polling the interface for mouse movement? What is your markup like? How is your CSS structured? It could be overlapping elements intercepting events before you want them to, it could be any number of things, but without any kind of code, it's really hard for anyone to do anything more than guess at what obstacles are in your path.

Comment: If you're using jQuery UI's Draggable/Droppable code, have you looked at setting this parameter? http://api.jqueryui.com/droppable/#option-tolerance ... it looks like you can set it to "touch" which means the droppable area is activated whenever the draggable touches with any part of itself the drop zone.

Comment: Thank you! That's what I was looking for. If you want to post your previous comment as an answer I'll mark it as correct and up-vote it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using jQuery UI's Draggable/Droppable code, have you looked at setting this parameter? http://api.jqueryui.com/droppable/#option-tolerance ... it looks like you can set it to "touch" which means the droppable area is activated whenever the draggable touches with any part of itself the drop zone.